# Как сделать динамическое удаление табов из панели navbar от bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, навигация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли с помощью bootstrap сделать навигационную панель/набор табов. так чтобы можно было с помощью скрипта добавить или удалить вкладки в навигацию

Answer (score 1):

Возможно. Делать с помощью javascript. Нужно написать js-код, который вставляет новый таб, т.е. по сути вставить в dom кусок html. 
Пример есть, например, на [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349281/twitter-bootstrap-dynamically-add-remove-tabs-and-tab-content):

http://jsfiddle.net/dogoku/KdPdZ/2/

Реализация нового таба:

```
function createTab() {
    var nextTab = $('#tabs li').size()+1;

    // создание таба
    $('<li><a href="#tab'+nextTab+'" data-toggle="tab">Tab '+nextTab+'</a></li>').appendTo('#tabs');

    // добавляем контент таба
    $('<div class="tab-pane" id="tab'+nextTab+'">tab' +nextTab+' content</div>').appendTo('.tab-content');

    // делаем активным
    $('#tabs a:last').tab('show');
}
```